# Cancel JQuery Validate Form

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-validate

I'm trying to have a cancel button on a pop in form but the form is submitted when the cancel button is clicked.

How do I: remove validate from the element, unbind the listener, or set a specific event for submit for my form so that it doesn't submit when the cancel button is clicked?

Thanks for your help

```
var form = document.createElement('form')
form.className = 'feedback_form corner_style'
form.remove = function() {this.parentElement.removeChild(this)}

var label = document.createElement('label')
label.innerHTML = 'Why did this not satisfy your need?'
form.appendChild(label)
form.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))

var textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
textarea.rows = 10
textarea.cols = 50
textarea.name = 'feedback'
form.appendChild(textarea)
form.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))

var submit = document.createElement('input')
submit.innerHTML = 'Submit'
submit.name = 'submit'
submit.type = 'submit'
form.appendChild(submit)

var cancel = document.createElement('button')
cancel.innerHTML = 'Cancel'
cancel.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('remove form')
  form.preventDefault()
  console.log('check 1 ')
  form.remove()
})
form.appendChild(cancel)

document.body.appendChild(form)
$(form).validate({
  debug: true,
  rules: {
    feedback: 'required'
  },
  submitHandler: () => {
    console.log('submit not_satisfied')
    $.ajax({
      url: '/not_satisfied',
      cache: false,
      data: {
        id: JSON.parse(row.dataset.extra_columns).id,
        feedback: 'NotImplimented'
      },
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
          console.log(String(jqXHR))
          console.log(String(textStatus))
          console.log(String(errorThrown))
          alert('Error processing request.')
      },
      success: data => {
        if (! data) alert('Could not complete request.')
      },
      complete: () => {document.dispatchEvent(new Event('only_nest_form_Submit_Complete'))}
    })
    form.remove()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably obvious to but I just needed to set the cancel button type to 'button'. [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

There is also the destroy method for the jquery validate that is not yet documented. https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1912

I was having problems with destroy because it was causing my page to reload, but on jsfiddle the page would not reload so be careful.